# How to register a global set of supported protocols for HTTPs in Apache HttpClient 4.5.3 Custom SSL implementation?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x, sslsocketfactory

Suppose I want to restrict the supported protocols used by Apache HttpClient 4.5.3 to only TLSv1.1. I can easily achieve that by the following code:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.createDefault();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                    new String[] {"TLSv1.1"}, null,
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());

CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://some-url");
httpclient.execute(httpGet);
```

I checked with -Djavax.net.debug=all enabled and verified that TLSv1.1 is being used. But for every instance of CloseableHttpClient I create, I need to do the above. Is there a way to set this configuration once and be effective for all CloseableHttpClient instances created? If I only do the following:

```
httpclient = HttpClients.custom().build();
httpGet = new HttpGet("https://some-url");
httpclient.execute(httpGet);
```

it always defaults to the TLSv1.2, which may be the HttpClient default.

My question is whether I can register the supported protocols in a way that even 
`HttpClients.custom().build();` would use only those specified protocols.

Got my example code from: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientCustomSSL.java

In the older HttpClient 3.1, I believe this could be achieved by the following code:

```
String scheme = "https";
Protocol customHttps = new Protocol(scheme, customFactory, defaultPort);
Protocol.registerProtocol(scheme, customHttps);
```

and customFactory is an object of a class that implements SecureProtocolSocketFactory, which internally sets the "enabled protocols" on the SSLSocket. The above code snippet registers the handler for "https" is what I understand.

Comment: Why would one _ever_ create more than a few HttpClient instances?

Comment: @oleg In this case multiple features of a webapp are making use of CloseableHttpClient in their own separate threads and access distinct URLs. Would you suggest a "factory" kind of approach which gives out CloseableHttpClient instances?

Comment: A factory would certainly be the most obvious choice here. Alternatively you might extend HttpClientBuilder and pre-populate desired attributes. More importantly though I am wondering if application threads should not be using the same HttpClient instance to start with.

Comment: Each thread uses it's own instance of CloseableHttpClient (I presumed by the name "Closeable" that the instance should be closed once the HTTP operation is done and is not thread safe). Thanks for the info! Big fan of HttpClient library since my early programming days and I knew you to be the author since! :)

Comment: HttpClient instances implement Closeable due to holding resources that need to be explicitly released / closed once no longer needed. This does not stop one from using the same instance of HttpClient for all threads for the entire duration of the application lifetime.

Comment: I see. I was under the wrong impression then! Gotta read the documentation correctly! :)